# Customize ticks and lables using scatterplot3d

Tags: r, label, scatterplot3d

My goal is to plot 9 names on my y axis (the letter "a" to "i" by one letter after another).

However only every second letter is being plotted using the function scatterplot3d in the program R. Do you know how I could solve this problem?

Sincerely

```
plot_how <- scatterplot3d(Test.df,
              color = "pink",
              main="test experiment",
              xlab = "time",
              ylab = "samples ",
              zlab = "output", type = "l", box = F,
              ylim = c(1,9),
              zlim = c(0, 3000), 
              grid = F, 
              yaxt = "n",  
              scale.y = 1, 
              label.tick.marks = T, 
              y.ticklabs = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the command `lab` in scatterplot3d. If you set the command to for example because of 9 letters set `lab = c(9,9,9)` depending on your axis. I will give you an example with a sample data.

```
Test.df <- data.frame(letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
                        x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9),
                        z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9))
```

Test.df data:

```
  letter x z
1      a 1 1
2      b 2 2
3      c 3 3
4      d 4 4
5      e 5 5
6      f 6 6
7      g 7 7
8      h 8 8
9      i 9 9
```

You can use this code:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
  plot_how <- scatterplot3d(Test.df,
                            color = "pink",
                            main="test experiment",
                            xlab = "time",
                            ylab = "samples ",
                            zlab = "output", type = "l", box = F,
                            ylim = c(1,9),
                            zlim = c(0, 9), 
                            grid = F, 
                            yaxt = "n",  
                            scale.y = 1, 
                            label.tick.marks = T, 
                            y.ticklabs = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
                            lab = c(9,9,9))
```

Output plot:

[image]

As you can see in the plot, all the letters are now on the axis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That was exactly my problem,